# first 50 positive numbers divisible by 4

Tags: c

This is the code I reached.
what I don't get is the condition where x should stop. I know what I wrote is wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int x, i;
    for(i=0; i<=50; i++)
        {
            for (x=0;x<=50 ;x++ )
            {
                if (x%4==0)
                printf ("%d\n", x);
            }
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Think of a `while` loop instead.

Comment: *"I know what I wrote is wrong."*  How do you **know**?  Does it fail a particular test case? (describe the test).

Comment: also your code is doing quite too much. You can quite easily derive which numbers will be divisible by 4: namely each 4th. So why not just increase by 4, and that 50 times?

Comment: yeah it does fail. the program prints the numbers divisible by 4 between 0 and 50 23 times. That's why I said it is wrong @abelenky

Comment: Why not just print `0, 4, 8, ...` by `+=4` each time?

Comment: because im supposed to use loops

Comment: Why make it more complicated than `for (i = 1; i <= 50; i++) printf("%d ", i*4);`?

Comment: All numbers divisible by 4 are positive.

Comment: On a completely unrelated note, you don't need a counter variable at all. The maximum value is 200 (50×4), which fits in 8 bits, and the counter would only need to go to 50, so only 6 bits would be needed for that. Since an `int` is guaranteed to be at least 16 bits in size, you could have the counter be stored in bits 15..8, and the value stored in bits 7..0. What use does this have? None AFAIK, but it is fun to be creative anyway. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution, as suggested by Art in a comment above:

```
for(unsigned int c=1; c<=50; c++)
{
   printf ("%d\n", c*4);
}
```

Original answer: One loop is enough. And increase by 4 (every 4th number is divisible by 4, and none else):

```
int curNum=4;
for (unsigned int c=1; c<=50; c++, curNum+=4)
{
   printf ("%d\n", curNum);
}
```

So you see we have two variables, one counts the numbers we have printed already (`c`), and the other contains the current number to be printed (`curNum`).

Answer (score 1):

With this code you are showing numbers less than 50 that are divisible by 4 & then you are printing it 50 times. Although your question has been answered but if you are hell bent on checking if a number is divisible by 4 & using two for loops, this might work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int x=0, i;
for(i=0; i<=50; i++)
    {
        for(;;)
            {
                if(x%4==0)
                  {
                    printf("\n%d",x);
                    x++;
                    break;
                  } 
                  x++;    
            }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while(i<50)
    {
        if (x % 4==0)
        {
            printf ("(result %d) %d is divisible by 4\n", i, x);
            i++;
        }
        x++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use nested `for` loops. Try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0, count = 1;
    while(1)
    {
        if (i%4==0)
            printf ("%d\n", i);
        i++; 
        if (count++ == 50)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you increment `i` only when `i%4 == 0`?

Comment: @devnull; This is what happens when you post your code without debugging :)

Answer (score -2):

you just need one for

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int n = 0;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while(n < 50)
        {
                if (i%4==0){
                 printf ("%d\n", i);
                 ++n;
                }
                ++i;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but that will only print the first numbers from 0 to 50 which are divisible by 4. This won't be 50 numbers

Comment: now it's correct. Therefore, +1 from me! Only thing to be debated is whether 0 is already a positive number (the first printed number by your program is 0)